# WOL can be used to shutdown PC?

Tags: shutdown, wake-on-lan

I just read an article about [WOL vs IPMI](http://blogs.citrix.com/2007/12/21/wake-on-lan-vs-ipmi-good-comments-from-ctp-shawn-bass/), it says "...used WOL to save millions of dollars by powering off idle desktops"(almost end at last paragraph but one), does it mean that WOL can be used to power off a desktop?

If so, how?

p.s. Does mainstream server support IPMI?

Answer (score 0):

No, Wake On LAN lets you turn *on* PCs, not turn them off. The idea is that PCs need to be on in the middle of the night so they can get automatic updates; rather than leaving them on all day and all night just to get occassional updates, you can turn them off at the end of the day and use WOL to turn them on only when you need to update them.